# How to use a ZMQ subscriber in Haskell with pipes

Tags: haskell, zeromq, haskell-pipes

I can get a ZMQ subscriber to work in Haskell, but would appreciate guidance on how to use that data with Pipes.  My attempt at writing a Producer fails at 'stack build' with the following error:

> Couldn't match type ‘Proxy X () c'0 c0 (ZMQ z)’ with ‘ZMQ z’
>
> Expected type: ZMQ z ()
>
> Actual type: Proxy X () c'0 c0 (ZMQ z) ()

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where
import Control.Monad
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import System.ZMQ4.Monadic
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as CS

fromZMQ :: (Receiver r) => Socket z r -> Producer String (ZMQ z) ()
fromZMQ sock = do
    msg <- lift $ receive sock
    yield (CS.unpack msg)
    fromZMQ sock

main :: IO ()
main = --do
  runZMQ $ do
    subSock <- socket Sub  ---subscriptionSocket
    subscribe subSock ""
    connect subSock "tcp://127.0.0.1:4998" 
    forever $ fromZMQ subSock >-> P.take 3 >-> P.print
```

Note, I want to consume data being published on ZMQ by a python script.

Comment: I suggest not using the monadic zmq API and rolling your own Monad if needed.  That or consider having an indirection to zmq via a Chan and worker thread that just transfers data to/from zmq.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas for the suggestion to investigate Chan.  As I think zeroMQ provides the buffering that Chan provides, I was able to get something to run using MVar which seems to neatly resolve the underlying issue I was wrestling with, ie. how to update a representation of state without getting the <<loop>> runtime error. Code below, in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Working off Thomas' suggestion of using Chan, I adapted the MVar example (link below) to accumulate the strings received and a count of them to demonstrate updating and reading state

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/ch07.html

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Concurrent  
import Control.Monad
import System.ZMQ4.Monadic
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as CS

newtype State = State (MVar (Int, [CS.ByteString]) ) --(count, list of strings received over zmq)

newState :: IO State
newState = do
  m <- newMVar (0, [])
  return (State m)

updateState :: State -> CS.ByteString -> IO ()
updateState (State m) newString = do
  (count,strList) <- takeMVar m
  putMVar m ( count + 1 , strList ++ [newString] )

showState :: State -> IO String
showState (State m) = do
  count <- takeMVar m
  putMVar m count  --return the lock; no changes
  return (show count)

main = runZMQ $ do
    sub <- socket Sub
    subscribe sub ""
    connect sub "tcp://127.0.0.1:4998"
    s <- liftIO newState 
    forever $ do
      receive sub >>= liftIO . updateState s 
      liftIO $ updateState s "hello"  --'manually' add an additional string on each iteration
      op <- liftIO $ showState s
      liftIO $ print op
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in your code is the last line.

You have a “pipe” there:

```haskell
fromZMQ subSock >-> P.take 3 >-> P.print :: Effect (ZMQ z) ()
```

and when you apply `forever` to it, the type remains the same. But what you need there is a simple `ZMQ z`, in other words, you need to actually perform the `pipes` computation and you use the `runEffect` function for this. As a side note, you don’t really need the `forever` as the stream will never end anyway.

So, all you have to do, really, is replace `forever` with `runEffect` in the last line.